# Qual a diferença entre ; e & em uma URL?

Tags: php, url

Estava observando um site para acrescentar em uma aplicação C#, notei um *link* parecido com esse:

```
www.site.com.br/index.php?post=yes;user=1521;
```

Os parâmetros são separados por `;`(ponto e vírgula). Acessei a mesma página trocando o `;`(ponto e vírgula) por `&`('e' comercial):

```
www.site.com.br/index.php?post=yes&user=1521
```

---

A página foi carregada normalmente, há alguma diferença entre `;` e `&`?

Comment: No título "web forms" tem uma explicação básica. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: É mais comum você ver usando & do que ;

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No [link comentado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) [pelo @Bacco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110175/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-e-em-url#comment228509_110175) temos a seguinte definição:

> - The query string is composed of a series of field-value pairs.
> - Within each pair, the field name and value are separated by an equals sign, '='.
> - The series of pairs is separated by the ampersand, '&' (or semicolon, ';' for URLs embedded in HTML and not generated by a ...; see below).

Resumindo um pouco:

> - As query string são compostas por pares de `campos=valor`
> - Cada serie de par é separada por <kbd>&</kbd>, ou <kbd>;</kbd> caso não seja proveniente de um form.

Contudo gostaria de mostrar o seguinte:

Se eu acessar um URL assim :

> www.site.com.br/index.php?post=yes|user=1521|pass=123|uf=RS
>
> www.site.com.br/index.php?post|yes|user|1521|pass|123|uf|RS

Você acha que pode não funcionar?

O fato é que o que vier apos o `?`, geralmente sera pego pelo `GET` da linguagem que você estiver trabalhando, e esta informação será uma `string`, como o seu código vai interpretar o que vier vai depender de sua codificação.

Answer (score 6):

O caracter semicolon `;` (vulgo "ponto e vírgula") pode ser usado como um separador de parâmetros numa URL. Todavia o caracter ampersand `&` é o padrão por convenção geral.

O semicolon é um subdelimitador. O uso é aplicável em schemas específicos. Exemplo, o schema "Prospero":

```
prospero://<host>:<port>/<hsoname>;<field>=<value>
```

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Note que a vírgula `,` também é um separador válido, porém sob o mesmo contexto pois ambos são classificados como subdelimitadores, de acordo com o [rfc3986](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt).

Consulte também: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.2

Answer (score 1):

O ; é reservado e pode ser usado por servidores para um tipo de separação de dados, como no seu exemplo claramente acontece, enquanto o & normalmente é usado para separação de parámetros GET. O ; pode porém ter outro uso/significado com outro servidor, por exemplo pode ter sistemas que usam ; dentro da parte por trás do & para separar várias partes da resposta.

Na prática tem relativamente poucos software de servidor padrão, e dentro de cada um desses pode ter um tratamento relativamente uniforme desses símbolos. Porém, cada servidor sim tem todo direito de usar esses símbolos como serve melhor para o aplicativo que está rodando, por isso de nenhuma forma é garantido que o & e ; sempre sejam equivalentes.

No seu caso usa C# e os API padrão parecem tratar tudo da mesma forma. Mas porque em C# pode criar seu próprio estilo de tratar tudo, nem aqui é 100% garantido. É só assim porque é predefinido assim.

Mais informações relevantes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2163803/what-is-the-semicolon-reserved-for-in-urls

Answer (score 0):

Resumidamente é isso:

Se usa `&` ou `;` em `query string` gerados pelo próprio código (HTML, ou JS) para separação de parâmetros.

Porém, o `&` pode ser usado **também** em `query string` gerados por um `FORM`, já o `;` **não**.